# Let's get critical: May 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Personal Finance & Money Stack Exchange](http://money.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://money.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How do I build wealth?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21886/how-do-i-build-wealth)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Creating S-Corp: Should I Name My Wife as a Director/Shareholder?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21570/creating-s-corp-should-i-name-my-wife-as-a-director-shareholder)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)
- ["Inflation actually causes people not to spend"... could it be true?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21794/inflation-actually-causes-people-not-to-spend-could-it-be-true)

  **Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [What is the best resource for determining a specific age-based asset allocation?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21807/what-is-the-best-resource-for-determining-a-specific-age-based-asset-allocation)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [As a contractor, TurboTax Business-and-Home or Basic?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21377/as-a-contractor-turbotax-business-and-home-or-basic)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Is my reimbursement taxable?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21517/is-my-reimbursement-taxable)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Do I owe state taxes for a temporary (4 month) residence in California?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21531/do-i-owe-state-taxes-for-a-temporary-4-month-residence-in-california)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [10-Year Treasury Future Quotes](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21607/10-year-treasury-future-quotes)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Can the interest on a cash out refinance for a rental property be claimed as an expense?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21706/can-the-interest-on-a-cash-out-refinance-for-a-rental-property-be-claimed-as-an)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Salary equivalency: London vs Berlin](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21782/salary-equivalency-london-vs-berlin)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)